# Reason for charset() giving different outputs in mysql command line client and mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql

While I was checking default string character set for a database using charset() function, below are the outputs as shown :

mysql command line client output for query - SELECT CHARSET('apple') - which is cp850
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1wiQ.png)

mysql workbench output for query - SELECT CHARSET('apple') - which is utf8mb4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYn9O.png)

According to the above, what is the reason for query showing different outputs in command line and workbench?

Comment: ?because the workbench default character set is utf8mb4..do you want to change to be consistent and which would you wish to change?

Comment: Quering the character set of a string literal you by fact query current `@@character_set_connection`. `CHARSET()` function usage makes sense only while applied to a column or an expression.